# load a json file in databricks spark then iterate through the json list

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Trying to figure out a way to load a json file into databricks spark, put the json in a dictionary, and iterate through it.

Right now I am trying to use `sc.textFile()` to load the file.

My json file looks like this:

```
{
    "tablename": "a",
    "tablename": "b",
    "tablename": "c",
       ...........
    "tablename": "z",
}
```

I want to iterate through the json file

Things I have tried:

```
data = json.load(open('data.json'))
```

did not work

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

did not work

Thank for any help

Comment: Are you trying to read this into an RDD or spark DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your json doesn't actually contain duplicate keys. If it does this might be the reason why your solution doesn't work.

Otherwise the following snipplet reads a json file into a dictionary and iterates through it in **Python 2.7**:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

with open('stuff.json', 'r') as file_handler:
    result = json.load(file_handler)

print(result)  # {u'tablename1': u'b', u'tablename0': u'a', ...}
print(type(result))  # <type 'dict'>

for key, value in result.iteritems():
    print('key: %s // value: %s' % (key, value))  # key: tablename1 // value: b
```

The code for **Python 3.6** is slightly different:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

with open('stuff.json', 'r') as file_handler:
    result = json.load(file_handler)

print(result)  # {u'tablename1': u'b', u'tablename0': u'a', ...}
print(type(result))  # <class 'dict'>

for key, value in result.items():
    print('key: %s // value: %s' % (key, value))  # key: tablename1 // value: b
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest answer is that you forgot the `.read()` method on your code

Using a file with info

```
{
    "tablename1": "a",
    "tablename2": "b",
    "tablename3": "c",
    "tablename4": "z"
}
```

and code

```
json.loads(open('foo.json'))
```

gives the result

```
{u'tablename1': u'a',
 u'tablename2': u'b',
 u'tablename3': u'c',
 u'tablename4': u'z'}
```